# How do I add elements below my navbar using bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have attempted to place elements below the navigation bar I created, however, it keeps distorting the NavBar. I have used bootstrap so I was hoping I could add a form underneath the code below, it's honestly just an issue of spacing and I have read the bootstrap documentation yet I still find it difficult. The code below is fine but could someone try to add a form or some kind of input box below it, please. Thank you, guys.

```
<! this is where the nav bar starts to be made>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
  <!this is the length and theme of the navigation bar is set>
    <ul class="navbar-nav pl-2">
      <! i've added padding left as i need to space out items in the nav bar well>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="Home.php" class="nav-link navbar-brand mt-2 ">District 1</a>
        </li>
        <! the home button is the name of the store>
          <div class="mx-auto">
            <form class="mx-auto order-0 col px-md-5">
              <! this is the creation of the search bar>
                <div class="mx-auto input-group mt-1">
                  <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 380px; margin-top: 5px;">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1"><img
                        src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/search--v2.png" alt="Search" class="mx-auto"
                        width="20" height="20"></button>
                    <! this is the image for the search button function>
                  </div>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon"
                    aria-describedby="button-addon1" style="margin-top: 5px;">
            </form>

          </div>

    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
      <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 120px;">
        <a id="one" href="SignIn.php" class="nav-link" style="font-size: 15px;">Hello, <br> Sign in!</a>
      </li>
      <! this is the sign in button>

        <li class="nav-item mr-5">
          <a id="two" href="SignIn.php" class="nav-link"><img
              src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/shopping-cart--v2.png" alt="Cart" width="40"
              height="40"></a>
        </li>
        <! this is the shopping cart button>

          </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: please post CSS code and update your answer so we can better help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are examples of input fields and forms below your nav, is this what you are looking for?

Please see comments in the code to understand better.

Comment if you have more questions.

```
.flex-c-row {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  margin:25px;
} /* setting the display to flex, which is by default 'row' with items side-by-side; give it align-items:center to align items vertically in the available space */

.flex-c-row > * {
  margin:50px; /* space all direct child elements of the outer container by 50px on all sides top bottom right left */
}

.flex-c-col, form {
  display:flex;flex-direction:column; /* same as above but set the flexbox direction of elements as a COLUMN so vertical */
}

input {
  cursor:pointer;
}

form > * {
  margin:25px 0;
}
```

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">
   <ul class="navbar-nav pl-2">
      <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="Home.php" class="nav-link navbar-brand mt-2 ">District 1</a>
      </li>
      <div class="mx-auto">
      <form class="mx-auto order-0 col px-md-5">
         <div class="mx-auto input-group mt-1">
            <div class="input-group-prepend" style="margin-left: 380px; margin-top: 5px;">
               <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon1"><img
               src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/search--v2.png" alt="Search" class="mx-auto"
               width="20" height="20"></button>
            </div>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="" aria-label="Example text with button addon"
            aria-describedby="button-addon1" style="margin-top: 5px;">
         </div>
     </form>
   </ul>
   <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto ">
     <li class="nav-item" style="padding-right: 120px;">
        <a id="one" href="SignIn.php" class="nav-link" style="font-size: 15px;">Hello, <br> Sign in!</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item mr-5">
        <a id="two" href="SignIn.php" class="nav-link"><img
           src="https://img.icons8.com/pastel-glyph/2x/shopping-cart--v2.png" alt="Cart" width="40"
           height="40"></a>
     </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
  
  <!-- so here we simply add the container div for our 3 input examples -->
  <div class="flex-c-row">
 <div class="flex-c-col">
   <span>This is an input field</span>
   <input type="datetime-local">
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <form>
      <h3>This is a basic form.</h3>
      <input>
      <input>
      <textarea cols="15" rows="25"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-c-col">
    <span>This is a color input field.</span>
    <input type="color">
    </div>
 <div>
```

Codepen to play with:
https://codepen.io/larrytherabbit/pen/pobjKLw

Comment: Thank you, loved the answer to this very much!

Comment: Glad I could help! Feel free to mark it as the Accepted answer if it helped : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work // also if anything else i'm around you can comment here

Comment: I was just wondering what parts of my code did you change because I can clearly see the section you added. Thank you! I know you removed the comments but what else?

Comment: In your original code I only removed your comments, then I added the missing closing `</ul>` tag at the end and put the closing `</div>` tag BEFORE the the closing `</form>` tag to respect `HTML` conventions. i.e. you cannot do `<form><div>something text</form><div>` you have to respect the order of your opening and closing elements... this might be useful to read quickly https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_syntax.asp

Comment: @Hugo if you want to go more in-depth that could be good too https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html

Comment: Thank you so much, that clarifies everything for me. I am quite new to coding.

Comment: Good My pleasure

Comment: However, why does the height of the navbar change height when the Form is added I wanted to keep it the same as I am using PHP to replicate the navbar over my website.

Comment: You can give `nav` a `max-height` value of `XXXpx` so it can't shrink or grow? You can set a `min-height` as well if you want.

Comment: It works but then items within the task bar do not stay aligned

Comment: yeah it's because there is a lot of CSS markup that comes from the boostrap css stylesheet that is kind of interfering with our efforts. let me check

Comment: To be honest, do you think I could create a navbar using a different method which would be better

Comment: Like for example if you look at the CSS markup for that element, it's quite complicated stuff... like there is a display:list-item property for it, like, it's the first time I even see this display type used haha. Look heree https://prnt.sc/uyq6r9  for sure we can create a muuuuch simpler navbar for you. Let me guide you give me 2-3 mins

Comment: Bootstrap and other "pre-built" libraries are usually bloated code and don't encourage you to *understand* your code.... my opinion.

Comment: can you send me an email instaed? I don't see your invite :( laurentchevrette@gmail.com